# Unexpected output in every case.What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++, string

Problem 131A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/131/A
My solution instead of doing what the problem asks,returns the same string which is inputted.What is wrong with my solution.

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int i,a;
char input[101];
int main()
{
    cin>>input;
    a=0;
    for(i=0;input[i]!=NULL;i++) //To find number of uppercase letters.
    {
        if(isupper(input[i]))
        a++;
    }
    if((a==strlen(input))|((a==(strlen(input)-1))&(islower(input[0])))) //To check for accidental pressing of Caps Lock(Words like Jingle or jINGLE.).
    {
        toupper(input[0]);
        for(i=1;input[i]!=NULL;i++)
        {
            tolower(input[i]);
        }
        cout<<input;
    }
    else
    cout<<input;
}
```

Comment: Don't you like the null character ?

Comment: indeed. do not use `NULL` as `'\0'`. technically `NULL` is not even guaranteed to have value 0, only to become `(void*)0` if used in a pointer-context.

Comment: `|` or `||`?  Beware.

Comment: What is `if((a==strlen(input))|((a==(strlen(input)-1))&(islower(input[0]))))` doing?

Comment: Are you certain you want bit-wise `|` and `&` and not logical `||` and `&&`?

Comment: According to the problem,we have to apply case changes only if words are of form 'HEISENBERG'or'hEISENBERG'.This statement checks for that.Integer a is number of uppercase letters.

Comment: Normally one would code with `||` and `&&` here, although in this limited case, either will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toupper()` or `tolower()` don't change their argument, but return the changed char. You must write `input[i] = toupper(input[i])`. Then you shouldn't do theese conditional checks with bitwise operators. Use `||` and `&&` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
toupper(input[0]);
```

doesn't change `input[0]` to upper case, it *returns* the upper-case equivalent of `input[0]`.

Try

```
input[0] = toupper(input[0]);
```

instead (and the same for every other toupper/tolower call).

Comment: toupper takes an int - are you worried about sign extension from signed char causing a problem?

Comment: @Useless-I changed that.Now I get the correct output for cases of form JINGLE,PING etc.The 2nd form(jINGLE,kLINGON etc.) still give wrong output.Is my logic for the following statement correct?

'if((a==strlen(input))|((a==(strlen(input)-1))&(islower(input[0]))))'

Comment: no, mb84 spotted you were using bitwise, instead of boolean, operators

Comment: @IamintheEmpireBusiness: bitwise would work, if you were sure, that every operation returns 0 or 1. but it seems that `islower()` returns something other than 0 when true (like it is specified). so it could be 2. when `(a==strlen(input)-1) == 1` then the bitwise `&` returns 0. because of this case you should always use in such cases `&&` and `||` to be sure that this logic is preserved: `0 == false` *everything* else `== true`

Answer (score 1):

`char toupper(char)` and `char tolower(char)` only returns converted character, and doesn't modify passed one (it would require reference or pointer usage). Instead use:

```
input[0] = toupper(input[0]);
for(i=1;input[i]!=NULL;i++)
{
    input[i] = static_cast<char> ( tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i]) ) );
}
cout<<input;
```